# LogicApp + Xpath expression invalid error

Tags: xpath, azure-logic-apps

I am using LogicApp to parse a XML response from Webservice.

In the below XML, I am trying to get the value 33 based on the element ID is el7.

- Expression_A:LogicApp expression is `xpath(xml(outputs('Compose')),'//infoRef[@el = "el7"]')`
- Expression_B:LogicApp expression is `xpath(xml(outputs('Compose')),'//*[@el='el7']')`

The xpath expression **//infoRef[@el = "el7"]** works as expected in Xpath tester (http://xpather)
The xpath expression **//*[@el='el7']** also works as expected in Xpath tester (http://xpather)

Expression_A: result is

```
[
  {
    "$content-type": "application/xml;charset=utf-8",
    "$content": "PG11bHRpUmVm.......I+MDwvbXVsdGlSZWY+"
  }
]
```

Expresion_B: unable to save expression as logicapp says invalid expression. I tried '' instead of ' around el7 like '//*[@el=''el7'']' and didnt help
either.

Pls advice if you have encountered similar issue and possible fix.

Regards,

Shortened XML is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <infoRef el="el7" soapenc:root="0" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xsi:type="xsd:int" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">33</infoRef>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have checked "Reference guide to workflow expression functions in Azure Logic Apps and Power Automate" and their recommended systax seems to be Expression_A but it doesnt seem to give the value 33 instead is returning  [{"$content-type":"application/xml;charset=utf-8","$content":"PG11bHRpUmVm.......I+MDwvbXVsdGlSZWY+"}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your expression to this ...

```
first(xpath(xml(outputs('Compose')),'//infoRef[@el = "el7"]/text()'))
```

... given you're using `//` in your XPath expression, it has the potential to return multiple elements, therefore, it comes back as an array.

`first()` (LogicApp expression) will get the single item and turn it into an object while at the same time, it will translate the base64 representation to text.

`text()` (XPath expression) will retrieve the value of the element rather than the XML representation.